# actionscript 2 collision detection

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, scaleform

I can achieve bounding box collision in AS2 but it's not accurate enough for my needs.

Here is my fla:[collisiontest](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=814B1F2A22D2C0C0!106&authkey=!AEe6FQv07K1vbGc&ithint=file%2Cfla)
Click and drag the car; you'll see the text box change to "true" when a collision is detected. You'll note it can be triggered well before the rotating bar touches the badly drawn car.

Is there any way to achieve per-pixel collision, or something close with AS2?

I'm tied to AS2 rather than AS3 because of the Scaleform implementation of the game engine I'm developing for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use MovieClip.hitTest with movieclip instances that have custom hit areas (using vector shapes). Use the hitArea property to define these custom hit areas.